# JAVA- how to convert letters in a string to specified number?

Tags: java, string

Please help me to write a java function to convert a string into numerical value

function must accept a string and it should returns a integer array that contains numbers

Each alphabet having a numerical value shown below:-

**1 = A I J Q Y**

**2 = B K R**

**3 = C G L S**

**4 = D M T**

**5 = E H N X**

**6 = O Z**

**8 = F P**

For string **"Stack overflow"**

Numerical value is = 3 4 1 3 2 7 6 5 2 8 3 7 6"

*for example:-*

***input:-*** String str = "Stack overflow";               .            .  . . .//ignoring spaces

***return*** array= {3,4,1,3,2,7,6,5,2,8,3,7,6};

Comment: please show some effort and write the code yourself. If you experience difficulties or get stuck, you are welcome to come back and ask for help.

Comment: map each character to a value. from there it should be an easy job. But no code for you!! Try yourself

Comment: How do you get a `7` in the result, even though this is not part of the key map?

Answer (score 6):

I would add your numerical values into a hashmap

```
{A=>1, I=>1, J=>1, Q=>1, Y=>1, B=>2, K=>2, ...}
```

Than you iterate the string, and lookup each value in the map, and add that to a list.
You may want to UpperCase your character, for the lookup.

```
for(Char c in input) {
    Integer n = lookup(c);

    if(found) {
        result.add(n);
    }
}
```

And at last convert your list to an int Array

Comment: +1 for providing a way to a solution without actually providing all the work.

Comment: did not know java got such super syntax

Comment: @IgorRodriguez I wrote that as joke comment for hashM init syntax

Answer (score 1):

Chuck all the letters into a map with the value being what you want.

E.g.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap(); 
hm.put ('A', new Integer (1));
hm.put ('B', new Integer (2));
```

Then to use

```
int arr [] = new int [myString.length ()];
for (int x = 0; x < myString.length ();) {
    Integer i = (Integer) hm.get (myString.charAt(x));
    if (i!=null) {
      arr[x++] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is not actually that bad, come on. At least he specified what he needs.

Comment: Oh, ok then.  Feeling lazy today ;-)

Comment: Your array may be to long, since not all characters of the input have a mapping. So there is empty space at the end of the array. This may lead to later problems, and I think it is against the OP's "specification".

Comment: I think he mis-typed it as he says `Each alphabet having a numerical value`

Comment: yes, but he also says *"ignoring spaces"*. And what about punctuation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First add your letters to a *HashMap*:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> yourMap = new HashMap<>();
yourMap.put("aijqy", 1);
yourMap.put("bkr", 2);
yourMap.put("cgls", 3);
yourMap.put("dmt", 4);
yourMap.put("ehnx", 5);
yourMap.put("oz", 6);
yourMap.put("fp", 8);
```

Then if you have a given String you can lowercase it and split it into single characters by using the "toLowerCase()" and "split()" method with an empty String for an argument.

You iterate over each letters and do:

```
String finalString = "";

for(String letter : yourString.split("")){
    for(Map.Entry entry : yourMap.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getKey().indexOf(letter) != -1){
            finalString += entry.getValue();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is so inefficient. no reason use hashmap if you iterate all items.

Comment: @JIV for the scale of the data, I would not worry about efficiency.   In fact I would upvote for creating a smaller mapset.

Comment: @JIV I've breaked it. Better?

Comment: @user2310289: yes in this case it doesnt matter but concept is wrong.

Comment: @Dropout: you still not using hashmap keys as keys, you could switch it even for List.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of java are you using? Since java 7, strings are valid switch statements.

Comment: Good solution! Even chars like 'A' or 'B' can be used since the beginning of Java time (not only since Java7)!

Answer (score 0):

check this by yourself for correctness

```
int [] arr={1,2,3,4,5,8,3,5,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,1,2,3,4,-1,-1,-1,5,1,6};

then  touppercase then ascii then add -65
then if(>0) or add those letters too
```

here is quick stuff(not some letters missing  )

```
  int [] arr={1,2,3,4,5,8,3,5,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,1,2,3,4,-1,-1,-1,5,1,6};

    for (char ch: "Stackoverflow".toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
         if(ch>='A' && ch<='Z'){
              System.out.println("value " + arr[((int)ch-65)]);
         }
    }
```

Here is for your case:

```
String str="Stack overflow".toUpperCase();
int res[]=new int[str.length()];
int lastindex=0;
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
     int ch=str.charAt(i);
     if(ch>=(int)'A'  && ch<=(int)'Z'){
          //if you want skip not mapped ones just add if(arr[(int)ch-(int)'A']>0)
         res[lastindex]=arr[(int)ch-(int)'A'];
         lastindex++;//ignoring others
     } 
}

for (int j=0;j<lastindex;j++){
     System.out.print ( res[j] +",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the output is: [3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2, 8, 3, 6] because the 'w' isn't in your mapping

```
        String convert = "Stack overflow".toLowerCase();
        Map<Character, Integer> mapping = new HashMap<>();
        mapping.put('a', 1);
        mapping.put('i', 1);
        mapping.put('j', 1);
        mapping.put('q', 1);
        mapping.put('y', 1);
        mapping.put('b', 2);
        mapping.put('k', 2);
        mapping.put('r', 2);
        mapping.put('c', 3);
        mapping.put('g', 3);
        mapping.put('l', 3);
        mapping.put('s', 3);
        mapping.put('d', 4);
        mapping.put('m', 4);
        mapping.put('t', 4);
        mapping.put('e', 5);
        mapping.put('h', 5);
        mapping.put('n', 5);
        mapping.put('x', 5);
        mapping.put('o', 6);
        mapping.put('z', 6);
        mapping.put('f', 8);
        mapping.put('p', 8);
        List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(char c : convert.toCharArray()){
            Integer find = mapping.get(new Character(c));
            if (find!=null) {
                out.add(find);
            }
        }
        return out.toArray(new Integer[out.size()]);
```